# Stored procedure issue in database

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I use this stored procedure to show documents are in pending

```
create procedure b
as
  select         
     dbo.DocumentInfo.DocID, dbo.DocumentInfo.DocName, 
     dbo.DocumentInfo.Uploadfile, dbo.DocType.Doc      Type,
     dbo.Department.DepType, ApproveType.ApproveType
 from 
     dbo.DocumentInfo 
 left join 
     dbo.DocType on dbo.DocumentInfo.DocTypeID = dbo.DocType.DocTypeID 
 left join 
     dbo.Department on dbo.DocumentInfo.DepID = dbo.Department.DepID 
 inner join      
     ApproveType on DocumentInfo.ApproveID = ApproveType.ApproveID 
                 and (ApproveType.ApproveID = 3)
```

but when I checked this query it can not show me any documents..

Where is the problem?

Comment: You have tagged `mysql-error-1045` are you actually getting this error?

Comment: sorry this is done by mistake ..i removed

Comment: Did you execute your code outside of procedure to see if it works?

Comment: Assuming you have all the relevant data and there are rows to return Im guessing you have an incorrect join somewhere.  Can you build the query bit by bit until you find the offending join. Maybe start by taking `ApproveType.ApproveType` out of the select then removing the join `inner join ApproveType on DocumentInfo.ApproveID=ApproveType.ApproveID  and (ApproveType.ApproveID=3 )` does it return rows?

Comment: yes in this end dbo.DocumentInfo.DepID=dbo.Department.DepID query works but when i try to this inner join      
   ApproveType  on DocumentInfo.ApproveID=ApproveType.ApproveID  and    
     (ApproveType.ApproveID=3 ) it can not show me data

Comment: please see this article http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0dc095de-a0dc-4884-ab5a-58ffe9abd3f0/store-peocedures?forum=sqldataaccess#a640c8f9-bb24-4545-91ac-6cdcf53a0e88

Comment: in the end i post whole problem with pictures here beacuse of less repuation i can not able to post pics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are straight joining (INNER JOIN) on a table to which the join is excluding data.  So either the column `ApproveID` in table `DocumentInfo` contains no data, or there are no matching rows in table `ApproveType` for column `ApproveID`.

It looks to me that you are using the join incorrectly in any case if you are going to be using this stored procedure in this way - and you could definitely look into using table aliases, as below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE b
AS
    SELECT  di.DocID, 
            di.DocName, 
            di.Uploadfile, 
            dt.DocType,
            d.DepType, 
            at.ApproveType
    FROM    DocumentInfo di
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
            DocType dt ON dt.DocTypeID = di.DocTypeID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            Department d ON d.DepID = di.DepID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
            ApproveType at ON at.ApproveID = di.ApproveID 
   AND  at.ApproveID = 3
```

Comment: it works for me but  it show me approvetype null how i show when any user upload document then approvetype pending and when approve then it changes to approve/reject